# Changing title of website to inform user about something

Tags: javascript, performance, title, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to update title of my website to show actual value of timer. like this (on the left)
[image]

This time should be updated. 
I found two ways of doing that in JavaScript

Either by setting

```
document.title = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Or by setting id on "title" tag, and getting this tag from JavaScript and changing it's textNode:

```
 <title id="title-tag">Tick-tock timer</title>


var titleTag = document.getElementById("title-tag"); // of course I won't get this element every time I change value, I will factor it out
titleTag.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

I wonder which of those methods are more appropriate/efficient ?

Comment: Try: `setInterval(function () { document.title = new Date(); }, 100);`

Comment: You don't need to use a id on the title tag. You can: `document.getElementByTagName('title');` since you should always have ONLY ONE `<title></title>` tag pair.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion should be no difference as far as this is done only once per second (if your timer is less than second e.g. 100ms, then check if it needs to be changed).

But the first way seems much more clear and correct for the guy who will support this code later.

**EDIT**

After I performed some tests (see [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/Owavipup/1/)) it is clear: first way is a bit faster.

But anyway, as I've mentioned before, this is not the point to think about in your case

Comment: This jsbin test look like infinite loop. It make my browser unresponsive!

Comment: this one runs both functions 1000000 times. I have Chrome, works quite fast (maybe 10 seconds in total). You can easily repeat the test, just run functions in loop many times and see the time, otherwise you cannot find what is faster